# Cassandra opscenter "agents failed to connect" on removed nodes

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I have some EC2 instances where cassandra provisioning failed. I terminated the instances and the machines no longer exist.

Opscenter keeps nagging me about "agents failed to connect" on these machines.

The machines do not show up in `nodepool status` nor in the `system.peers` table.

Where does cassandra opscenter stores the node list to connect to so I can delete these zombie nodes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a bug in OpsCenter that is being addressed in the future. To mitigate your current issue, just restart OpsCenter and those messages should cease.

Comment: Ok, should have thought about simply restarting opscenter... This works, thx!

Comment: Worked for me : OpsCenter 5.1.4